# How to set path for src to the folder, that is outside the current project folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, capistrano3

I've uploaded a video to the DigitalOcean server into a `apps/project_name/shared/public` folder. In my html I have a `<video>` tag. I need to make a path to the `public` folder, that is located outside my `~current` folder. What is the best way to do it? I could push the video to the git repository, but it is not a good way, I think. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `public` is usually a shared folder when deployed with capistrano and can be referenced just like usual. Is that not how you're setting things up?

Comment: So, how should the path look like? `<source src="public/my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">`, or `<source src="shared/public/my_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">`. Or may be thease two options are wrong?

Comment: You directly access anything in public with just `my_video.mp4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've added to my `deploy.rb` `'public/video/my_video.mp4'` and `'public/video'`, so now it looks like:

```
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'config/puma.rb',
                                                 'public/video/my_video.mp4')
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle',
                                               'public/system', 'public/uploads', 'public/video')
```

and moved my video file to `public/video` directory and in the `source` I have this path now: `<source src="video/StadiumDataBackground.mp4" type="video/mp4">`

Comment: You don't have to include individual video files, just the public folder itself should be in "linked_dirs"